# Handling type erasure in constructors with generics

Tags: java, generics, constructor, type-erasure

I am trying to make a class that can hold only one of two objects and I want to do this with generics. Here is the idea:

```
public class Union<A, B> {

    private final A a;    
    private final B b;

    public Union(A a) {
        this.a = a;
        b = null;
    }

    public Union(B b) {
        a = null;
        this.b = b;
    }

    // isA, isB, getA, getB...

}
```

Of course this won't work though because due to type erasure the constructors have the same type signature. I realize one solution is to have a single constructor taking both, but I want one of the values to be empty, so it seems more elegant to have single parameter constructors.

```
// Ugly solution
public Union(A a, B b) {
    if (!(a == null ^ b == null)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("One must exist, one must be null!");
    }
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

**Is there an elegant solution to this?**

---

> **Edit 1:** I am using Java 6.

> **Edit 2:** The reason I want to make this is because I have a method that can return one of two types. I made a concrete version with no generics but was wondering if I could make it generic. **Yes, I realize that having a method with two different return types is the real issue at hand, but I was still curious if there was a good way to do this.**
>
> I think [durron597's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31881625/1858327) is best because it points out that `Union<Foo, Bar>` and `Union<Bar, Foo>` should act the same but they don't (which is the main reason why I decided to stop pursuing this). **This is a much uglier issue than the "ugly" constructor.**
>
> For what it's worth I think the best option is probably make this abstract (because interfaces can't dictate visibility) and make the `isA` and `getA` stuff `protected`, and then in the implementing class have better named methods to avoid the `<A, B>` != `<B, A>` issue. I will add my own answer with more details.

> **Final edit:** For what it's worth, I decided that using static methods as pseudo constructors (`public static Union<A, B> fromA(A a)` and `public static Union<A, B> fromB(B b)`) is the best approach (along with making the real constructor private). `Union<A, B>` and `Union<B, A>` would never realistically be compared to each other when it's just being used as a return value.

> **Another edit, 6 months out**: I really can't believe how naive I was when I asked this, static factory methods are so obviously the absolute correct choice and clearly a no-brainer.
>
> All that aside I have found [Functional Java](http://www.functionaljava.org/) to be very intriguing. I haven't used it yet but I did find this [`Either`](https://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/2.20/javadoc/fj/data/Either.html#left()) when googling 'java disjunct union', it's exactly what I was looking for. The downside though it that Functional Java is only for Java 7 and 8, but luckily the project I am now working on used Java 8.

Comment: You can hide your "ugly solution" constructor behind factory methods.

Comment: you  should use interface here

Comment: Static factories are the way to go in general. Though if you've got two fields that are mutually exclusive, that's always suspicious.

Comment: Looks like the beginnings of another `Either` monad to me... so why don't you take a look at any from a sizable offering of already completed implementations.

Comment: I would use an abstract base class and two subclasses for the different types.

Comment: @Marko I looked up "unions in java" and a colleage showed me apache commons' `Pair`, I will look up this `Either` class

Comment: Will A or B ever be different types? Like `new Union<String, Integer>`?

Comment: @Khelwood the problem with hiding the constructor leads to the same issue though, `public static of(A a)` and `public static of(B b)` have the same type signature. I suppose there is `ofA` and `ofB` but that doesn't seem terribly elegant. (There may not *be* an elegant way to do this with generics.)

Comment: Factory methods will have the same problem as constructors, erasure will cause them both to have the same parameter. And you can't have a and be as final with builders. I am afraid the answer to the question is "no, there is not". Ask for reified generics in Java 9

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos No need to overload. Just provide two differently named methods. One for a, one for b.

Comment: Yes, you need different method names. Something you can't get for a constructor. I don't see the big deal, though.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Reification has nothing to do with static types, and this is a static typing issue. Plus, only the specifics of how type erasure is done for java makes type erasure a problem. Static FP languages also do type erasure, but don't suffer from this.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis. I tried that and indeed it works. Though you must lose final.

Comment: @Zymus they will always be different, if they were both `A` or both `B` I'd just use `A` or `B` instead of this `Union<A, B>`

Comment: What ia the primary use case of this? I can't imagine any scenario where this would be wanted or necessary. If you could give us more information, it might make it easier to divine the desired outcome.

Comment: @Zymus You can read on the use cases for an `Either` monad. The Web is chock-full of it, but [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ft13/)'s one that may give a good intro.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - dude, let's not call everything a "monad" :) and in java we probably should never use the term at all.

Comment: @bayou.io I am usually the one to point that out :) But, monads being such a fashion today, I initially thought OP was dabbling with the concept already. OTOH, "monad" is not such a "big word" really, it's just a class with `flatMap` and an appropriate constructor. Since OP is on Java 6, this aspect won't be a big win for him, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't really make any sense to do this. When would this ever make sense? For example (assuming, for the moment, your initial code worked):

```
Union<String, Integer> union = new Union("Hello");
// stuff
if (union.isA()) { ...
```

But if you did, instead:

```
Union<Integer, String> union = new Union("Hello");
// stuff
if (union.isA()) { ...
```

This would have **different behavior**, even though the classes and the data are the same. Your concept of `isA` and `isB` are basically "left vs right" - it's more important which one is left vs right than which one is a String vs which one is an Integer. In other words, `Union<String, Integer>` is very different from `Union<Integer, String>`, which is probably not what you want.

Consider what would happen if we, for example, had, say:

```
List<Union<?, ?>> myList;
for(Union<?, ?> element : myList) {
  if(element.isA()) {
    // What does this even mean?
```

The fact of something being an `A` doesn't matter, unless you care about whether it's a Left or a Right, in which case you should call it that.

---

If this discussion is not about left vs right, then the only thing that matters is using your specific types when creating the class. It would make more sense to simply have an interface;

```
public interface Union<A, B> {
  boolean isA();
  boolean isB();
  A getA();
  B getB();
}
```

You could even do the "is" method in an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractUnion<A, B> {
  public boolean isA() { return getB() == null; }
  public boolean isB() { return getA() == null; }
}
```

And then, when you actually instantiate the class, you will use specific types anyway...

```
public UnionImpl extends AbstractUnion<String, Integer> {
  private String strValue;
  private int intValue

  public UnionImpl(String str) {
    this.strValue = str;
    this.intValue = null;
  }

  // etc.
}
```

Then, when you've actually chosen your implementation types, you'll actually know what you're getting.

---

Aside: if, after reading all of the above, you still want to do this the way you describe in your initial question, the right way to do it is with static factory methods with a private constructor as described [@JoseAntoniaDuraOlmos's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31881499/1768232). However, I hope you think further about what you actually need your class to do in a real use case.

Comment: Very good point! Union<Integer,String> should behave as Union<String,Integer>

Comment: Good call about `A, B` and `B, A`, I am not sure the best approach to handle that. `is(Class<?> clazz)` possibly? Seems even more ugly...

Comment: The only problem is, your sketch doesn't bring any improvement. Your `Union<A, B>` discriminates as radically between the left and the right type argument as OP's. The type of `getA()` is `A`, which is statically known to be the value of the left type parameter. Asking `isA()` does not ask about the _type_ of the instance, but only about its _state_: whether it is legal to call `getA()` or `getB()`, and both of those types are fixed before even running the program.

Comment: In this light, the split between interface and implementation is irrelevant to the subject of the question. The presence of runtime polymorphism changes nothing about static type resolution.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I agree that the second half of my answer doesn't address any of the problems I present in the first half of my answer. It was just an attempt to... "help", I guess.

Comment: Your failure to do so is fundamental: you cannot "abstract away" the static types and hope to stay typesafe. But I don't see the point of your criticism, either: there is actually nothing wrong with referring to the position of the type arguments ("left one", "right one") because they are always known (and _fixed_) for each given expression in the code.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a private constructor and 2 static creators

```
public class Union<A, B> {

        private final A a;    
        private final B b;

        // private constructor to force use or creation methods
        private Union(A a, B b) {
            if ((a == null) && (b == null)) { // ensure both cannot be null
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        public static <A, B> Union<A, B> unionFromA(A a) {
            Union<A,B> u = new Union(a, null);
            return u;
        }

        public static <A, B> Union<A, B> unionFromB(B b) {
            Union<A,B> u = new Union(null, b);
            return u;
        }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Factory methods are not checking that parameter is not null.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos : It was not in initial constructor example, but it is easy to check.

Comment: True, the question was unclear in that regard; doing it one way earlier and another later.

Answer (score 2):

If you must use a constructor then most likely there is not an elegant solution.

With factory methods you can have an elegant solution which preserves final for a and b.
The factory methods will use the "ugly" constructor but that is ok since it is part of the implementation. The public interface keeps all your requirements save for moving from constructors to factory methods.

This is made with the intention of making `Union<A,B>` interchangeable with `Union<B,A>` as per [durron597's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31881625/956880).
That is not entirelly possible as I'll show later with an example, but we can get quite close.

```
public class Union<A, B> {

    private final A a;
    private final B b;

    private Union(A a, B b) {
        assert a == null ^ b == null;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static <A, B> Union<A, B> valueOfA(A a) {
        if (a == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        Union<A, B> res = new Union<>(a, null);
        return res;
    }

    public static <A, B> Union<A, B> valueOfB(B b) {
        if (b == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        Union<A, B> res = new Union<>(null, b);
        return res;
    }

    public boolean isClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return a != null ? clazz.isInstance(a) : clazz.isInstance(b);
    }

    // The casts are always type safe.
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <C> C get(Class<C> clazz) {
        if (a != null && clazz.isInstance(a)) {
            return (C)a;
        }
        if (b != null && clazz.isInstance(b)) {
            return (C)b;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("This Union does not contain an object of class " + clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Union)) {
            return false;
        }
        Union union = (Union) o;
        Object parm = union.a != null ? union.a : union.b;
        return a != null ? a.equals(parm) : b.equals(parm);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 71 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.a);
        hash = 71 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.b);
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Here are examples of how to use and how not to use it.
`useUnionAsParm2` shows the limitation of this solution. The compiler cannot detect a wrong parameter used for a method which is meant to accept any Union containing a String. We have to resort to runtime type checking.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Union<String, Integer> alfa = Union.valueOfA("Hello");
        Union<Integer, String> beta = Union.valueOfB("Hello");
        Union<HashMap, String> gamma = Union.valueOfB("Hello");
        Union<HashMap, Integer> delta = Union.valueOfB( 13 );
        // Union<A,B> compared do Union<B,A>. 
        // Prints true because both unions contain equal objects
        System.out.println(alfa.equals(beta));    

        // Prints false since "Hello" is not an Union.
        System.out.println(alfa.equals("Hello")); 

        // Union<A,B> compared do Union<C,A>. 
        // Prints true because both unions contain equal objects
        System.out.println(alfa.equals(gamma));   

        // Union<A,B> compared to Union<C,D>
        // Could print true if a type of one union inherited or implement a
        //type of the other union. In this case contained objects are not equal, so false.
        System.out.println(alfa.equals(delta));

        useUnionAsParm(alfa);
        // Next two lines produce compiler error
        //useUnionAsParm(beta);
        //useUnionAsParm(gamma);

        useUnionAsParm2(alfa);
        useUnionAsParm2(beta);
        useUnionAsParm2(gamma);
        // Will throw IllegalStateException
        // Would be nice if it was possible to declare useUnionAsParm2 in a way
        //that caused the compiler to generate an error for this line.
        useUnionAsParm2(delta);
    }

    /**
     * Prints a string contained in an Union.
     *
     * This is an example of how not to do it.
     *
     * @param parm Union containing a String
     */
    public static void useUnionAsParm(Union<String, Integer> parm) {
        System.out.println(parm.get(String.class));
    }

    /**
     * Prints a string contained in an Union. Correct example.
     *
     * @param parm Union containing a String
     */
    public static void useUnionAsParm2(Union<? extends Object, ? extends Object> parm) {
        System.out.println( parm.get(String.class) );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Union" is the wrong word here. We are not talking about the union of two types, which will include all objects in either types, possibly with overlapping.

This data structure is more like a tuple, with an extra index pointing to one significant element. A better word for it is probably "option". In fact, `java.util.Optional` is a special case of it.

So, I might design it like this

```
interface Opt2<T0,T1>

    int ordinal();  // 0 or 1
    Object value();

    default boolean is0(){ return ordinal()==0; }

    default T0 get0(){ if(is0()) return (T0)value(); else throw ... }

    static <T0,T1> Opt2<T0,T1> of0(T0 value){ ... }
```

Comment: I used the word union because it's similar to the idea of a union in C. Also, I am using Java 6 so `java.util.Optional` isn't an option (pun unintended and not regretted). But I do have guava so its version is available (in fact, I am using `Optional<A>` instead, but I wanted to be minimalistic in my question).

Comment: The fundamental difference between the C `union` and your class is that C's is completely type-unsafe: you can interpret the value as an instance of any of the declared types, at any time. You, however, aim for a typesafe solution (otherwise you'd just be returning `Object` and cast to any type you want).

Answer (score 0):

As [durron597's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31881625/1858327) points out, `Union<Foo, Bar>` and `Union<Bar, Foo>` should, conceptually speaking, behave the same but behave very differently. It doesn't matter which is `A` and which is `B`, it matter which is which type.

Here's what I think may be best,

```
// I include this because if it's not off in its own package away from where its
// used these protected methods can still be called. Also I specifically use an
// abstract class so I can make the methods protected so no one can call them.

package com.company.utils;

public abstract class Union<A, B> {

    private A a;
    private B b;

    protected Union(A a, B b) {
        assert a == null ^ b == null: "Exactly one param must be null";
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    // final methods to prevent over riding in the child and calling them there

    protected final boolean isA() { return a != null; }

    protected final boolean isB() { return b != null; }

    protected final A getA() {
        if (!isA()) { throw new IllegalStateException(); }
        return a;
    }

    protected final B getB() {
        if (!isB()) { throw new IllegalStateException(); }
        return b;
    }
}
```

And the implementation. Where this is used (except for `com.company.utils`) only the methods with unambiguous names can be found.

```
package com.company.domain;

import com.company.utils.Union;

public class FooOrBar extends Union<Foo, Bar> {

    public FooOrBar(Foo foo) { super(foo, null); }

    public FooOrBar(Bar bar) { super(null, bar); }

    public boolean isFoo() { return isA(); }

    public boolean isBar() { return isB(); }

    public Foo getFoo() { return getA(); }

    public Bar getBar() { return getB(); }

}
```

---

Another idea may be a `Map<Class<?>, ?>` or something, or at least to hold the values. I don't know. All this code stinks. It was birthed from a poorly designed method that needed multiple return types.

Comment: Yes, this `FooOrBar` class completely kills your original idea. But I don't actually see anything wrong with using the positional concepts of left and right type. Your method will declare to return a `Union<String, Integer>` and you will know perfectly well which is left and which is right type. Remember that you cannot turn the static type system into a dynamic one, and statically the difference between left and right is very clear. You cannot possibly remove that ordering.

Comment: Remember the key idea behind your original concept: you are solving the problem of an impossible "method with two return types" by transforming it into a method which returns one type, but whose _state space_ segregates into "left" and "right" states, each of these having a static type assigned to it.  This is exactly what the `Either` monad is a perfect fit for (and you are on your way to reinvent it).

Comment: @Marko what is an `Either` monad?

Comment: Try the reference I gave in my last comment under your question. That's a good explanation.

Comment: @Marko I looked the `Either` up, and yes, I do think for a return type it is the best solution. I don't think a moment where if it's `<A, B>` interacting with `<B, A>` would ever realistically arise.

Comment: If it ever arises, you'll be able to write a simple function which translates between the two.